# change background color in suggesting text In Eclipse IDE

Tags: eclipse, ide, user-experience

I have turned on the dark mode in eclipse. when I coding something on it and it suggest me available things as usual. But the problem is now the 1st of the suggestion is in black background and black text.

[image]

this suggesting text is is unreadable in the first element .

I want to make it readable.

Answer (score 2):

You can change the background and the foreground colors of the content assist of the HTML Editor in the **preferences *Web > HTML Files > Editor > Appearance***. Choose black or a dark color for ***Completion proposal background*** and white for ***Completion proposal background***.

Comment: Still not working . I want to edit it not only for html .I want to make it support all file types .the suggesting keywords still in black colour .

Comment: Choose black or a dark color for _Completion proposal background_ and white for _Completion proposal background_: see my edited answer.